# Dual screen setup via VGA and HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, vga

I want to use to 27 inch 1080p monitors with my laptop, and my laptop has one HDMI output and one VGA output. My laptop has a 2gb Radeon card, and the screen is 1080p.

I am just curious if the picture/color/respone time will be the same on both monitors being that they are being connected differently.

Thanks!

Comment: You will hardly notice any difference in day to day activities. I connected my 32 inch TV (1080p) to my laptop using VGA cable and it works well. Using it like that for last 6 years to watch movies.

Comment: I have had laptops which support both being used at the same time.. I have also had laptops which disable one port when using the other.  You should make sure it works before getting too deep into this.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor connected via VGA should display a worse picture/color quality than HDMI simply because VGA-Display Mode officially supports 256 colors instead of the approximately 1 billion  colors possible in HDMI v1, but as pointed out to me it is possible to use true-colour in 24 bit mode.

The response time **should** also be lower because VGA supp0rts 70Hz and HDMI v1 can support up to 120Hz. I wrote should because **most** monitor manufacturers limit the HDMI response rate to 60Hz, but this is entirely dependant which monitor, HDMI cable and GPU you use.

You should look up which HDMI version your graphics card and Monitor supports. Standard is HDMI v1.3 or higher. You should also check if your graphics card support three monitors at the same time (two external and laptop display).

All that aside as this was purely technical stuff. You may not even notice the difference between the HDMI connected display and the VGA one. I personally have both connected to my PC and I really don't notice a difference, but that is also dependant of your cable and display quality.

Comment: `VGA only supports 256 colors` is not correct. Nearly every monitor can handle 24-bit color using a standard VGA connector.

Comment: @Sandeep The specification for VGA is 256 colors (as far as I could find out) that doesn't mean that it can not support more

Comment: That's true for VGA display mode. VGA connector supports true color which is 24 bit.

Comment: @Sandeep I edited it. I hope it's good enough. If not you are free to edit it yourself or notify me again. :)